# Reacting to a "wrong-type-argument"

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

So I'm starting to learn a bit of lisp/elisp to optimize my emacs environment, and I've started making a simple emacs library, the major roadblock is being able to tell if a parenthesis entered has a match or not. I've been looking through the emacs source (paren.el.gz) and realized I can use the function `show-paren-function` to determine if it is a match or not.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
(defun it-is-a-paren()
  (interactive)
    (insert ")")
    (if (show-paren-function)
        (message "%s" "it is a match") 
      (message "%s" "it is not")))
```

So this is pretty basic, and "it is a match" works as it should, but when it is supposed to throw "it is not", it doesn't, instead it gives me "Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, t".

Is anyone familiar enough to advise use of a different function, or maybe I should be writing my own altogether instead of using `show-paren-function`. Or is there a way around this error (sort of like exception handling)?

Comment: You can also try the standard function [backward-sexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) which also throws an exception if the parens are unbalanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "exception handling"-like construct you're looking for is `condition-case`.

```
(defun its-a-paren()
  (interactive)
  (insert ")")
  (condition-case ex
      (if (show-paren-function)
          (message "its a match")
        (message "its not"))
    (error (message "its not"))))
```

**Edit:** Looking into `show-paren-function`'s code, it seems to me that this error is a bug as it comes from the expression `(goto-char pos)` where `pos` is `t`.

Anyways, `show-paren-function` uses `scan-sexps` to look for the matching paren. Adapting from the way it's done in `show-paren-function`, a simplified function for your case would be:

```
(defun its-a-paren()
  (interactive)
  (insert ")")
  (condition-case ()
      (progn
        (scan-sexps (point) -1)
        (message "It's a match"))
    (error (message "It's not a match"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the if as stated worked perfectly, I am also unsure if it is the actual way for show-paren-function to tell it can't find a match.

Comment: Your `condition-case` will match errors of type `error` and of type `quote` (an error type which does not exist) because of the extra ' you've added before `error`.

Answer (score 2):

Using show-paren-function for this purpose is overkill (like giving your car to a garage a checking if the oil-level has changed, to determine if the car needed more oil) and doesn't work right, as you've noticed.

I'd recommend you try

```
(condition-case nil
    (progn (forward-sexp -1)
           (message "Moved to the matching opener"))
  (scan-error (message "No matching opener")))
```

Comment: Since `forward-sexp` changes point, I think it would be needed to wrap your code within a `save-excursion` form.

Comment: Thanks @stefan! I was aware it probably wasn't the right way, I was just trying to hack together a working prototype before I started refactoring.